# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because public definition for getenumerator mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

on this line I am getting an error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

```
 public ActionResult RoleCreate()
 {
 userType type = new userType();
 List<DomainView> EmpList = type.GetAllRoleModulesViews();
 List<ViewRoleModules> modules = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
 Role objBind = new Role();
 objBind.DomainViews = EmpList;
 foreach (DomainView emp in EmpList)
{
  int modID = emp.DomainID;
  foreach (ViewRoleModules mod in modID)
  { 

  }
}

return View(objBind);
}
```

Modules:

```
public class DomainView
    {
        [Key]
        public int DomainID { get; set; }
        public string DomainCode { get; set; }
        public string DomainName { get; set; }
        public int TabOrder { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<DomainView> DomainViews { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class ViewRoleModules
    {
        [Key]
        public int ModuleID { get; set; }
        public int DomainID { get; set; }
        public int ParentModuleID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyTypeID { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int TabOrder { get; set; }
        public string Style { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string IsTab { get; set; }
        public string ApprovalProcess { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public string DomainName { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ViewRoleModules> ModuleViews { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: tittle]

Comment: The error message is clear. modID is an integer and you cannot iterate an integer.

Comment: what can i do i need to pass ID value to `ViewRoleModules` @AndyG

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you are trying to do. This is an XY problem. You have a list of some entity and want to map that to another entity or whatever, and your `foreach (var x in someInt)` isn't going to do that.

Comment: you should pass emp i think

Comment: We do not know what the connection is between an `emp.DomainID` and ViewRoleModules.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as below:

```
foreach (ViewRoleModules mod in modules)
{ 
}
```

You are using `modId` instead of `modules`
`modId` is `int` and not a collection

You still need to populate `modules` collection to get some output.

Comment: They just initialized modules to `new List<>`. It's not going to contain anything, so this suggestion is not a solution. Yes, it is an enumerable that's in scope, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for each in a collection like Array or List or Dictionary.
Example like

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
```

but from your code it is a single int variable

```
int modID = emp.DomainID;
```

you could not iterate a int variable as a collection, hence you receive this error.

From my understanding to get the desired output change the DomainView class as

```
public class DomainView
    {
        public int DomainID { get; set; }
        public string DomainCode { get; set; }
        public string DomainName { get; set; }
        public int TabOrder { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<DomainView> DomainViews { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ViewRoleModules> ModuleViews { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the for loop

```
foreach (DomainView emp in EmpList)
        {
            foreach (ViewRoleModules mod in emp.ModuleViews)
            {

            }
        }
```

but make sure you have linked the database and get the ViewRoleModules for the specific DomainView using the code inside the business logic

> type.GetAllRoleModulesViews();